# Authenticated Outbound Calls

Tags: apex, trigger, rest, apexrest

I am sending an outbound call when an update is done in account. I am using REST Service and sending data as json from salesforce to my API.
Now how do i authenticate this call.

**APEX Class**

```
public class WebServiceCallout {

@future (callout=true)
public static void sendNotification(String name, String city) {

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    req.setEndpoint('http://my-end-point.com/newCustomer');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody('name='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(name, 'UTF-8')+'&city='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(city, 'UTF-8'));
    req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }

}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger AccountCallout on Account (after insert) {

    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        // make the asynchronous web service callout
        WebServiceCallout.sendNotification(a.Name, a.BillingCity);
    }

}
```

Comment: How do i know the call made is done by salesforce and not someone else

Answer (score 3):

The authentication will depend on the server consuming SF request, as it will be validating the request, not on Salesforce. SF will be responsible to setup the request (create HTTP headers and body) in a format accepted by your server.

For a very basic example, you can define some random Private key. Store this key in SF and send it to your application every time SF connects to your application. You application will verify this and will process the request. Make sure communication is happening over HTTPS protocol, otherwise anybody can sniff this key.

Add some additional timestamp mechanism to make it more complicated to break.

Note: This is not a standard way to implement authentication. You should always rely on methods provided by your server.

You can also encrypt data sending to your app using OOTB SF Crypto class
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

Update:

Assuming your application supports basic authentication. Salesforce can create the authorisation header and will send it in the outgoing callout.

```
HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
r.setEndpoint('https://my.domain.com');
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
r.setMethod('GET');
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(r);
```

Comment: Any way to implement Basic HTTP authentication

Comment: OK i found this example on my sites. I have a doubt The username password fields are of salesforce  ? and how do i check it on my service ? What needs to be checked and how ?

Comment: I have c# rest API as endpoint url. The rest service consumes all this data

Comment: Yes they are SF username and Passwords and I would not suggest to hardcode them. My first question would be "Do you even understand how APIs work?"

Comment: I am a beginner sir, I do understand a bit. I have developed an outbound callout using a trigger and made a rest service which updates the value recieved on basis of email.  But i am technically weak in the field of authentication and salesforce